# How to write dataframe columns as a YAML file

Tags: python, pandas, yaml

I have dataframe like this:

```
class    params
classA   {'key1':value1,'key2':value2,'key3':value3}
```

I want to generate a yaml file like this:

```
class: class A
params:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
```

How can I do this in efficient way?

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your df with `print(df.head().to_json())`? I'm requesting that because since you have a `dict` in that df, it's a bit ambiguous as to whether it's actually a dict or just a string of a dict.

Comment: Or maybe run `print(type(df['param'].iloc[0]))`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a pandas DataFrame to YAML in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66667905/how-to-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-yaml-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data in `params` are actually `dict`s, and not just strings, this would be very simple using [`pyyaml`](https://pypi.org/project/pyyaml):

First install `pyyaml`:

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Then use it in conjunction with `df.to_dict()`:

```
import yaml
yaml_text = yaml.dump(df.to_dict('records'))
print(yaml_text)
```

Output:

```
- class: classA
  params:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
    key3: value3
```

(The `-` at the beginning is array notation - `class` and `params` are keys of an object in that array. That's because `df.to_dict('records')` returns a list of objects.)

If the data inside `params` *are* strings, if the JSON contained in them is valid, you can use the built-in function [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast
df['params'] = df['params'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

...and then use `yaml.dump`.